# Selenium zip file export and upload after extracting

Tags: selenium, automation

I have a feature which is Exporting a Zip file which will have a JSON file in it.I need to extract that ZIP and upload the JSON file to the system.

Could you please help me to automate this process using selenium ?

Comment: Selenium is for pure web application automation. Downloading a file->Unzip it->Upload to system(same / different) can be achieved by  methods provided by language binding you may be using. e.g. you can use java.util.zip.* methods to unzip file and further file handling to upload.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. i was thinking towards selenium only..